# Is there a term for sentences which structurally reflect their meaning?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Is there a term for sentences which structurally reflect their meaning?

Here are some examples:

1. I write less.
2. The last word of this sentence is "anything".
3. I ALWAYS WRITE IN UPPERCASE AS IF I'M YELLING!!!!
4. Why is this question ending with a question mark?

Is there any general term for such sentences?

Comment: This sentence no verb.

Comment: Self-reflexive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**self-referential**

The definition of self-referential according to the [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/self-referential):

> (Especially of a literary or other creative work) making reference to itself, its author or creator, or their other work

In this case, *making reference to itself* is the most relevant

Comment: This sentence is not self-referential.

Answer (score 1):

In perhaps a slightly modified sense, "illocutionary" (as opposed to constative) is used to denote a speech act that performs (as opposed to describes) an action. cf. Austen *How to Do Things with Words.*

Answer (score 1):

I should call it an ***[instantiative](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/instantiative)*** sentence, one that itself supplies an instance of what it is talking about.

The classic example is from Alexander Pope’s “[An Essay on Criticism](http://poetry.eserver.org/essay-on-criticism.html)”:

> These Equal Syllables alone require,
>   Th**o’ o**ft th**e Ea**r th**e o**pen Vowels tire,
>   While Expletives their feeble Aid **do** join,
>   **And ten low Words oft creep in one dull Line,**
>   . . . 
>   Then, at the last, and only Couplet fraught
>   With some unmeaning Thing they call a Thought,
>   A needless Alexandrine ends the Song,
>   That like a wounded Snake, drags its slow length along.